# No sound with a Creative Labs Soundblaster live EMU10K1X

Tags: 11.10, sound

I just installed ubuntu. things seems great but I have no sound. When I go to the settings menu I chose from various setup. I found one that work which had 4 speakers a subwofer and a front speaker. When I test it the sound works fine. However, when I try playing an *.mp3 file or try to watch a video on you tube I get no sound at all. I have a dual boot with windows XP and there is no problem in windows at all. Below is my setup.

OS: ubuntu 11.10
machine: dell dimension 8300
speakers: dell creative lab sounblaster live EMU10K1X
video: ATI RADEON R350 [Radeon 9800 Pro] secondary

Following https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems did not help.

Answer (score 0):

try https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems

There is a basic trouble shooting guide.

Comment: Nope, that didn't help at all. On the positive note, I learn a few new things.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked all volume levels, not only the ones accessible via sound indicator in the GUI but also via terminal with `alsamixer`?